# Regex in Notepad++ "Replace Text + Value" ==> "New Text + Value"

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I rewrote some stuff and now I need to replace a lot of files they contain the following:

```
TOOL_ID = 1
```

and

```
TOOL_NAME = "Calc"
```

It needs to be replaced to:

```
Application_ID = (1)
```

and

```
Application_Name = "Calc"
```

My attempts are the following so far:

`(?<=TOOL_ID = )`  this returns at least the 1.
But I am unsure how I can put it to a proper output. Since if I do:

Application_ID($&) it just replaces it, with : TOOL_ID = Application_ID1 (it don't even uses the "()")

Hope someone got some sweet tips :)

Comment: Match `TOOL_ID\h+=\h+(\d+)` and replace with `Application_ID = ($1)` https://regex101.com/r/OYcSg4/1

Comment: For the replacement you'll also need to escape the parenthesis. So `Application_ID = \($1\)`. (Don't ask me why though.)

Comment: When I do it this way in Notepad++ it ignores the () it just put it like : Applicaton_ID = 1 but without the ()

I also added a second case, maybe you can take a look :)


Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:(TOOL_ID) = (\d+)|(TOOL_NAME) =)`
- Replace with: `(?1Application_id = \($2\))(?3Application_Name = )`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                     # non capture group
    (TOOL_ID)           # group 1, literally
    =                   # equal sign
    (\d+)               # group 2, value
  |                   # OR
    (TOOL_NAME) =       # group 3, literally
)
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1                         # if group 1 exists (TOOL_ID)
    Application_id =          # replace with Application_id
    \($2\)                    # the value suround with parentheses that have to be escaped in Notepad++
)                           # end if
(?3                         # if group 3 exists (TOOL_NAME)
    Application_Name =        # replace with Application_Name
)                           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have those 2 values, you could use 2 capturing groups and use a conditional replacement.

```
\bTOOL_(ID|NAME)\h+=\h+(?:(\d+)|("Calc"))
```

Or to match word chars instead of `Calc` and `ID` or `NAME`

```
\bTOOL_([A-Z]+)\h+=\h+(?:(\d+)|("\w+"))
```

*Explanation*

- `\bTOOL_([A-Z]+)` Match Tool_ and capture in **group 1** 1+ uppercase chars A-Z in group 1
- `\h+=\h+` Match `=` between 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `("\w+")` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ word chars between double quotes
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P0IT2t/1)

In the replacement test for group 2. If that exists, replace with group 1 and 2 or else replace with group 1 and 3.

```
Application_(?{2}$1 = \($2\):$1 = $3)
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't replace `TOOL_NAME` with `Application_Name`

Comment: May be it's a typo in the question but they want to replace `NAME` (all uppercase) with `Name`

Comment: @Toto Perhaps it is a typo, you use  `Application_id` in the replacement instead of `Application_ID` and that seems ok for the OP :-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, apart from the ending parenthesis around the number 1:
[image]